# KDE task switcher spam: "the window switcher installation is broken, resources are missing."

Tags: kde, kde5, plasma5

Invoking the task switcher (I use `<Alt-Tab>`) prompts a (very distracting) message box:

[image: Window/Tasks Switcher error message]

If I release `<Alt-Tab>`, but then activate it shortly after, it will continue to grow, as such:

[image: Window/Tasks Switcher multiple error messages]

I'm running Debian 9.2, e.g. Stretch, on a HP Probook 6450b.
None of the base switcher effects works, and neither does the downloadable ones I've tried.
The *switching itself* works, there's just no effect, or preview of any windows, it just switches instantaneously.

**Questions:**

1. **What could be causing this?**
2. **How can I solve it?**

**Edit:** [I found a bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=804638). Reported *Nov. 2015*, maintainer* answered *Aug. 2016*, and then, silence. Doesn't bode well.

* *I assume*

Comment: KDE5 plasma is still not rock solid stable, so there are a lot of bugs now. If this bug is new then please report it: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=kde-plasma-desktop;dist=stable

Comment: @IporSircer It's fairly solid on Arch Linux. This looks like a packaging issue. Switching works for me. But yeah, if you don't get anything useful here, you'd probably just want to contact Debian about this.

Comment: I [found a bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=804638), but it really doesn't bode well, especially considering how minor a bug it is.

Answer (score 11):

> The window switcher installation is broken, resources are missing

It seems you downloaded some theme or custom task switcher that is not compatible with your current version.

I had same problem and fixed it **selecting a working theme**, **then restarting** (or relogging), **using following command** :

`kwin_x11 --replace`

Hope it helps.

Comment: This did the trick for me.  I'm pretty sure my issue was caused by a package update without restarting the session.

Comment: can you be more specific about "theme"?  which theme did you pick?  i seem to get this no matter which "desktop theme" i pick.

Comment: @Jayen using a default one instead of custom themes : https://imgur.com/a/xTddYoO same for task switcher

Comment: thanks.  it turned out just having a broken theme installed broke all the themes.  after uninstalling it, all the other themes worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

In `systemsettings5`, go to workspace->window management->task switcher. Here, under "Visualisation", try choosing something different from the drop-down (for example, I had the problem you describe when "Cover switch" was selected). Click Apply in the lower right corner. Then, bring up the run dialog (alt+f2 unless you changed the hotkey) and enter `kwin_x11 --replace`, followed by ENTER. "Breeze Dark" instead of "Cover switch" worked for me, fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen because of broken switch layout/theme (like "compact" one). Try to delete all downloaded theme, choose one from default list and restart kwin (or reboot system).

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  Your answer might be good start, but needs some more detail to be helpful:  How should someone "delete themes" -- should they delete files from a specific directory?  How can they tell which themes are "downloaded" or "default"?